# logging not writing to file when called from function in Pyscripter

Tags: python, logging, pyscripter

Currently if I run the following code from the python command line it writes to the file specified by `filename` as expected.

```
import logging
def test():
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                        filename=r'C:\Users\theo\Documents\myLog.txt')
    logging.warning('Example logged message.')
test()
```

But when I copy the code into one of my functions and run the function with Pyscripter, it does not seem to write the file.
How can I get logging to appear in Pyscripter?

Comment: You're going to need to show us some code, and generally give us more information. Is the function in the top-level script, or an imported module? Are you actually doing the `import logging` and `logging.basicConfig(…)` in the function? (Also all the dumb stuff, like: is the function actually being called?)

Comment: Consider http://pastebin.com/CWbDTb0c

Comment: the filename appears different in both snippets, is this actually the case?

Comment: the actual filepath is very long, the file paths shown are more representative. I guarantee the filepath does exist.

Comment: `\\Stuff\test.log` is not a valid UNC path on Windows, and it's not even a valid _kind of path_ on any other platform I know of. But changing it to, e.g., `./test.log`, your code works properly for me on Windows, OS X, and Linux (as long as I run it from a writable directory). (I only tested with 3.2 on Mac; on Windows and Linux I didn't have it handy, so I used 3.3. But I doubt that's relevant.)

Comment: Its a shared drive, perhaps this is the issue? I'll test it on a local path and see if it works.

Comment: only the first call to `basicConfig()` does something. Do you have basicConfig() calls anywhere else in your code?

Comment: No, shared drives have at least two components. `\\Stuff\Share` can be a UNC path for a share, but `\\Stuff` cannot (it's a UNC path to a host, and you can't open files directly on a host).

Comment: My bad i was unaware of this, the path listed is not the real path. I've updated to reflect your point.

Comment: @J.F Sebastian all the code I am running is above. Running test does not write to the file for me, which is my problem.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that the problem here has nothing to do with "in a function" vs. "not in a function", and everything to do with "using a valid path" vs. "using an invalid path". Even if it's not directly obvious, it's probably something like using relative paths, and the difference is that your "in a function" case is being run from a different current drive/directory. Without actual testable code, there is nothing to debug here.

Comment: consider adding a print statement inside of the function at the end of it just to make sure it it in fact getting called and that it is not hanging on execution inside

Comment: Is there actually a valid, writeable network share called `\\Stuff\folder`? If you just `with open(r'\\Stuff\folder.test.log', 'w') as f: f.write('test')` instead of using `logging`, does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyscripter has an 'External Run' option ( Run > External Run (Alt + F9)), choosing this made the logging work.

Comment: Just want to add the "External Run" method is accessed by the menu option Run > External Run (Alt + F9), with the logging information directed to the Output tab rather than the Python Interpreter tab.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the Python Engine to Internal. Go to run-->Pyhton Engine-->Internal