# Python Script Will Not Log

Tags: python, logging

I am using pyscripter to write python and am having trouble with the logging. I have my code below which does not log to the console like [this source](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) says it should. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import logging

def main(argv=None):

    logging.debug('Beginning process')
    logging.info('Beginning process')
    logging.warning('Beginning process')

    print "This is printing so why won't the logging work?"
```

If anyone knows why this code isn't working it would be a great help.

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: @dano Pressing the run button in pyscripter. The rest of my script opens configuration files and performs http requests to multiple places and prints messages to the console however the part which should be easy(logging) seems to be difficult

Comment: Have you configured logging anywhere? `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` is a start.

Comment: @tdelaney I don't have to --> Check out the link in my question to the python doco. For the most basic example which outputs to the console you do not need to do anything else. (at least I expect the warning to log but not the other two)

Comment: This seems to be an issue with pyscripter: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17223964/190597 and http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/issues/detail?id=685.

Comment: @unutbu that was definitely the issue. It now works as I would expect when I look at your links and change how I'm running it. If you would like to write an answer with that information I'll mark it otherwise I'll add an answer later today :) ( also big thanks - this was slowing me down )

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Per SO convention, I'll close this one as a dupe.